# Animating div content populated by AngularJS without jQuery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, css-transitions

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>
```

I create the alerts in angularjs (and I'm using bootstrap), and while this works great, the visual effect is kind of uncool.  As alerts are added to the div, all page content is shoved ungracefully down to make room for the new alert.

I would like to animate the movement so that it is at least smooth.  But I don't want to use jQuery.  I've played with the CSS3 transitions, but can't seem to get them to work smoothly.

Can I do this where the trigger is a change in div height?  How?

Comment: Check out this articles on Angular animations: [Enhanced Animation in AngularJS](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/05/enhanced-animations-in-angularjs.html) and [Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Comment: Those articles are what I'm looking at now.. things are getting a bit crazy though- like to use angularjs 1.1.5 or 1.2.0?

Comment: If you can choose either one, go for 1.2. The animation system was rebuilt and it's much more simple to use, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with directives in their link function. i think you wont mind about so small piece on jquery code

```
myModule.directive('animateRight', function () {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var right = function() {

            $(this).animate({
                {"height": "800px"},
                "fast");
            })
        }

        element.on('click', right);
    };

     return {
    restrict:'A',
    link:linker
}
})


<div animate-right class="box"></div>
```

Comment: That's not a small piece of jQuery.  jQuery is doing all of the animating.

Comment: you can say that there are 3 lines of jquery code,does it matter?
a lot of work is doing the directive,you could do as Michael said,but that is compared to this a lot of code...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't like to answer my own question, but this seems like the way to do it...

I used AngularJS 1.2, along with the new ngAnimate module.  You need to add angular-animate.js, and reference the animate module, so at the end here's what my modules looked like:

```
var app = angular.module('tracker', ['$strap.directives', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

After that, its super simple, and very much CSS3 animations.  My alert line ended up with a class `repeat-item`:

```
<alert class="repeat-item" type="alert.type" data-ng-repeat="alert in alerts" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

And I added some CSS to target that class with the angularjs triggers:

```
.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.2s linear all;
    transition: 0.2s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}

.repeat-item.ng-leave,
.repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And `voila` a nice fade in and out animation.

[This page](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#how-to-make-animations-in-angularjs) really explains very well how to do it. Cheers to Michael Benford for the great link.